# Proof of Heine-Borel Theorem: Is this proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ A subset of a Euclidean space is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

$\textbf{Proof:}$
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose $A$ is closed and bounded. By boundedness, there exists some $R>0$ such that $A \subseteq B(0,R)$, and by closedness, $A \subseteq \bar{B}(0,R)$, where $\bar{B}(0,R) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x|\leq R\} = [-R,R]\times[-R,R]\times...\times[-R,R] \: (n \text{ times})$.
By Tychonoff's theorem, $\bar{B}(0,R)$ is compact, and so $A$ is the closed subset of a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So $A$ must be compact.

Conversely, suppose $A$ is compact. Fix $x_0 \in A$. Then given $x\in A$, we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B(x_0,n) \subseteq A$. So $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B(x_0,n)$. So there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}B(x_0,n)$. So $diam \:A= sup\: \{d(x,y): x, y\in \: A\}\:\leq\: 2N$. Hence $A$ is bounded.

$\textbf{Lemma}$ [Theorem 2.37, Baby Rudin]: If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $A$ in amteric space, then $E$ has a limit point in $A$.

$\underline{Proof \:of\: Lemma:}$ If no point of $A$ is a limit point of $E$, then every $x\in A$ has a neighborhood $V_x$ such that $V_x$ contains at most one point of $E$, namely, $x$, if $x \in E$. But no finite subcollection of $V_x$ covers $E$, and therefore $A$, since $E\subseteq A$. This contradicts the compactness of $A$.

Now we use the Lemma above: Suppose $A$ is not closed. Then there is a limit point $x'$ of $A$ which is not in $A$.Being a limit point, then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x_n \neq x', \:x_n \in A$ with $|x_n-x'|<\frac{1}{n}$. Let $S$ be the set of all such $x_n$. Then $S_n$ is infinite and the limit of $S$ is $x'$, but $x'\notin A$. This contradicts the lemma.

Is this my proof of the Heine-Borel theorem acceptable? I feel that something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: The "compact implies closed" part can be done more directly. Just take a sequence $(x_n)$ of $A$ that converges to $x \in E$. By compacity of $A$, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in $A$. But the limit of this subsequence is $x$, so $x \in A$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe : While I agree with you, I feel like at the level of this question, proving sequential compactness implies compactness is just as hard, if not harder, than proving the claim in question. No?

Comment: @zugzug I agree that it is always confusing to know what you are allowed to use and what you are not... But I used "compact implies sequentially compact", which is (I guess ?) the easy way of the equivalence in metric space.

Comment: Note that when $n\ge 2$, the ball is not a product of closed intervals. Also you did not prove that $[-R, R]$ is compact.

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh really? I didn't realize that. Please could you give an example of that?  And, is it correct to say rather, that the (closed) ball is contained in a product of closed intervals?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, thanks for your response. Is my hypothesis that any point of $A$ is contained in some closed ball $\bar{B}(x_0,n)$ correct?